# What is a symmetric channel?

Tags: information-theory, noise

In one of the assignments I was asked to explain whether the given channels are symmetric. For instance, $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, the matrix describes a conditional distribution, e.g., $p(decode_1|encode_1)=p(decode_3|encode_2) =0.5$
$$Q_1 = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0.5   & 0.3 \\
        0.2   & 0.2 \\
        0.3   & 0.5 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
        ­
$$Q_2 = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0.5   & 0.2 \\
    0.2   & 0.3 \\
    0.3   & 0.5 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I was wondering what is the formal **definition of a symmetric channel**? Didn't see it in my lecture, tried Wikipedia, only find a topic on binary symmetric channels. Is there a more extended definition of symmetric channels other than binary?
­

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to R.C. Gallager, "Information theory and reliable communication", Wiley (1968):

> A DMC is defined to be symmetric, if the set of outputs can be
>   partitioned into subsets in such a way that for each subset the matrix of
>   transition probability has the property that each row is a permutation of
>   each other row and each column is a permutation of each other
>   column.

DMC = discrete memoryless channel.

Comment: Do we always think of channels as symmetric. Are asymmetric channels also studied in literature. I know it is late to ask, Please help.